# InDesign: suddenly Update TOC deletes everything

Tags: adobe-indesign

I had a document I was adding text to, with a TOC. I updated the TOC several times, everything was OK.
Then I realized a chunk of text in the document wasn't in its place, so I cut and pasted it in the right place.
Then I clicked "Update TOC" and everything after the TOC title disappeared. The entire document.
I tried undoing and redoing the update, I tried reopening InDesign, I even tried returning the text to its previous place. I tried erasing the TOC and re-adding it. Nothing.
What is happening?

Comment: Is the rest of the text in text frames that are threaded to the same story as the TOC? Or are they separate stories?

Comment: A common, known issue with updating TOC. At some point in time InDesign decide it no longer like updating TOC so it will erase content, crash, corrupt file, make content in pages shrink to 0x0 mm boxes in the centre of a spread and so on. Adobe advise to update to newest InDesing (hint: it won't help in documents where this problem already appeared). Have a well made styles for TOC and make then new each time. Or make one for the first time at the end of working with document